# Dual monitor confusion in Ubuntu Gnome 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, display, multi-monitor

<sup>N.b. Since this is an issue on a machine running "[Ubuntu +1 (alpha)](https://askubuntu.com/q/18641/38585)", it's [out-of-bounds](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/871/38585) on AskUbuntu, so I'm hoping for some help here.</sup>

I encountered some odd screen behaviour this morning. I have been using Ubuntu Gnome 17.10 (alpha2) for a couple weeks now quite happily, with primary monitor on the right, and secondary on the left with spanned wallpaper -- all correctly displayed, and mouse correctly travelling from the far left edge of the secondary monitor, across the middle divide, to the far right edge of the primary monitor.

But this morning this behaviour has changed:

- the primary/secondary monitors are correctly identified;
- and the panels appear only on primary (as is correct in my setup);
- **but** the wallpaper is reversed, and the top left of the right (primary monitor) seems to be "0,0", so the mouse travel from the far right of the primary monitor, then appears on the *far left* of the left monitor (and the centre seam is a hard boundary).

`xrandr` reports:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3600 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 connected 1680x1050+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 474mm x 296mm
   1680x1050     59.95*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DP-3 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94
```

And `~/.config/monitor.xml` appears to be correct (so far as I understand it):

```
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>1680</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>DP-3</connector>
          <vendor>HWP</vendor>
          <product>HP LA2405x</product>
          <serial>CN43220DJ0</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1200</height>
          <rate>59.950672149658203</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-2</connector>
          <vendor>DEL</vendor>
          <product>DELL 2209WA</product>
          <serial>H735H9862DNL</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1680</width>
          <height>1050</height>
          <rate>59.954746246337891</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

And if I remove `monitors.xml`, the Display Settings dialog does **not** create a new one.

However, **there is a discrepancy here**: while `monitors.xml` correctly puts the Dell (secondary, physically on the left) at "0,0", the output of `xrandr` shows what I actually see, that the HP (primary, physically on the *right*) has the "0,0", and the Dell to the left of it is offset by 1920 (i.e. they are "virtually" reversed).

So "Display Settings" sees them incorrectly, i.e., as `[#1][#2]` although they *ought* to appear as `[#2][#1]`. This is what happens when I try to save the correct Display Settings with "Arrange Combined Displays":

[image: settings-dialog]

The setting simply doesn't "stick", and "Primary" ***always*** reverts to the left, instead of staying on the right.

`Shutter` sees my monitors/desktop as the Display Settings combined displays depicts it:

[image: combined-displays]

But this is what I actually see:

[image: monitor-photo]

How can I persuade Gnome Ubuntu to recognize that my desktop 0x, 0y should be the upper left of the *secondary* monitor, not the primary?

Comment: I have similar symptoms, haven't tested shutter though.
There is an issue posted on launchpad that touches this as well. 

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1715021

Comment: Thanks for the bug link. I see that since your comment was posted, another bug has been linked as related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1714410 So there is hope of a fix soon, anyway!

Comment: I'm flagging this question since it is a bug with an Ubuntu beta that will be fixed before release.

Comment: Nope not fixed, still problematic in production release of 17.10...

Comment: @ChristofKälin That's odd - it has been fixed for me for some weeks now. Have you run all the post-upgrade updates? (Although why this wouldn't be in the release itself is a puzzle.)

Comment: Yup, everything went smooth with the upgrade. But I think, there might be a bug with the display settings and/or monitors.xml (in .config). It ignores the scaling 2. Other times it resets dual monitor positions etc. I already have deleted the whole dconf just to be sure. I might try to delete all gnome-related stuff in .config this evening.